# SQL get date range

Tags: sql-server, vb6

How can I get the data that I need by using the ff date range(from-to)? The dates in my database has different formats: m/d/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy. And I need to get those dates by using the date range provided from my datepicker. Here's my SQL query:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM CIC_1047 WHERE (DOL >= '" & FormatToDate(dtFrom.value) 
AND DOL <= '" & FormatToDate(dtTo.value) & "') OR (DOL >= '" & FormatToDate2(dtFrom.value) & "' AND DOL <= '" & FormatToDate2(dtTo.value) & "') OR (DOL >= '" & FormatToDate3(dtFrom.value) & "' AND DOL <= '" & FormatToDate3(dtTo.value) & "') OR (DOL >= '" & FormatToDate4(dtFrom.value) & "' AND DOL <= '" & FormatToDate4(dtTo.value) & "') ORDER BY DOL asc, Name"
```

FormatToDates are my date functions.

Comment: Could you neaten up your code sample here?  It is currently very difficult to read as it is mostly all on one line and your single and double quotes don't properly pair off.  Also, what are the different numbers in your `FormatToDate` functions for?  What are the differences in the date functions?

Comment: Just to be sure about what we are talking: Your dates within the same database have different formats? Are you sure this are Datetime columns?

Answer (score 0):

Internally SQL Server dates are stored as 2 integers. The first integer is the number of dates before or after the base date (1900/01/01). The second integer stores the number of clock ticks after midnight, each tick is 1⁄300 of a second.
A negative number represents a date earlier than January 1, 1900.

Example: a date `2013-10-02 12:00:00` is stored as number 41547.5

Format dates from datepickers to ISO-8601 format and try this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM CIC_1047 WHERE DOL >= '" & FormatToIsoDate(dtFrom.value) & "' AND DOL <= '" & FormatToIsoDate(dtTo.value) & "'"
```

https://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2015/04/how-to-use-iso-8601-for-date-and-datetime.html